# Select two documents using iOS Document Picker in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, document, picker

Document picker enables the selection of a single document from Drive, Box, etc. However, I would like to be able to select a second document prior to leaving the interface so that I do not have to drill down through the folder structure a second time. Unfortunately, the protocol dismisses the pop-up once a document is selected. Ideas, alternatives?

Comment: Since this picker is provided by Apple, I think your best hope is to subclass everything needed (could be quite a bit) and alter as needed. Yes, this is quite a bit of work - but that's what it would take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting multiple files will be possible with iOS11 by setting “allowMultipleSelection” Boolean to true for your UidocumentPicker https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller/2902365-allowsmultipleselection

Comment: Have you been able to make this work? Even though the `allowsMultipleSelection` property is set to `true`, it still only lets me pick a single file at a time.

Comment: Yes, 11.1.2, but it still will only let me select a single item

Answer (score 0):

They deprecated [`documentPicker:didPickDocumentAtURL:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerdelegate/1618680-documentpicker) for [`documentPicker:didPickDocumentsAtURLs:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerdelegate/2902364-documentpicker) instead, and exposed [`allowsMultipleSelection`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller/2902365-allowsmultipleselection) in iOS11, but even with this I do not seem to be able to select multiple urls in the document browser.